# Can 1 approximation algorithm be used for multiple NP-Hard problems?

Tags: algorithm, np-hard

Since any NP Hard problem be reduced to any other NP Hard problem by mapping, my question is 1 step forward; 
for example every step of that algo : could that also be mapped to the other NP hard?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm we see that

NP-hard problems vary greatly in their approximability; some, such as the bin packing problem, can be approximated within any factor greater than 1 (such a family of approximation algorithms is often called a polynomial time approximation scheme or PTAS). Others are impossible to approximate within any constant, or even polynomial factor unless P = NP, such as the maximum clique problem.
(end quote)

It follows from this that a good approximation in one NP-complete problem is not necessarily a good approximation in another NP-complete problem. In that fortunate world we could use easily-approximated NP-complete problems to find good approximate algorithms for all other NP-complete problems, which is not the case here, as there are hard-to-approximate NP-complete problems.

Comment: For maximum clique problem, there is no O(lg n)-approximation algorithm unless P = NP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Hardness_of_approximation

Answer (score 2):

When proving a problem is NP-Hard, we usually consider the decision version of the problem, whose output is either yes or no. However, when considering approximation algorithms, we consider the optimization version of the problem.

If you use one problem's approximation algorithm to solve another problem by using the reduction in the proof of NP-Hard, the approximation ratio may change. For example, if you have a 2-approximation algorithm for problem A and you use it to solve problem B, then you may get a O(n)-approximation algorithm for problem B, since the reduction does not preserve approximation ratio. Hence, if you want to use an approximation algorithm for one problem to solve another problem, you need to ensure that the reduction will not change approximation ratio too much in order to get a useful algorithm. For example, you can use [L-reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-reduction) or [PTAS reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PTAS_reduction).

Comment: The reason is not clear, you are mixing 2-approximation algorithm with O(n) approximation...